# Combining array values in pairs without pairing with previous elements in array

Tags: php

i'm having trouble with combining array values. I have tried to combine them and make pairs something what i have done already but i want to erase some pairs that i do not want. Please some one to help me this happen .

```
// the Code I have now is:
$inputarray = array('Mussafiri', 'Fire', 'Ubungo', 'Mbezi'); 
$outputarray = array(); 
  $i = 0; 
   foreach($inputarray as $values) {
      $j = 0;      
      foreach($inputarray as $values2) { 
        if($values != $values2){    
            $outputarray[] = array($values => $values2); 
        }         
      $j++;     
     }     
 $i++; 
}  
print_r($outputarray); 

//Output  array is:
       Array (   [0] => Array ( [Mussafiri] => Fire) 
                 [1] => Array ( [Mussafiri] => Ubungo)  
                 [2] => Array ( [Mussafiri] => Mbezi)  
                 [3] => Array ( [Fire] => Mussafiri)  
                 [4] => Array ( [Fire] => Ubungo)  
                 [5] => Array ( [Fire] => Mbezi)  
                 [6] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Mussafiri)                                    
                 [7] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Fire)  
                 [8] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Mbezi)  
                 [9] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Mussafiri )  
                 [10] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Fire)  
                 [11] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Ubungo) )

NOTE: I DO NOT WANT THE FOLLOWING PAIRS TO APPEAR, I want element to pair with the next element and not pair with the previous element so i do not like index 3,6,7,8,9,10 and 11 to appear in the pair list i.e  
                  [3] => Array ( [Fire] => Mussafiri)                    
                  [6] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Mussafiri)  
                  [7] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Fire)  
                  [8] => Array ( [Ubungo] => Mbezi)  
                  [9] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Mussafiri)  
                  [10] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Fire)  
                  [11] => Array ( [Mbezi] => Ubungo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to create all unique pairs from the array, in which case something like this should work:

```
$pairs = array();
foreach ($inputarray as $key => $value) {
  for ($i = $key + 1; isset($inputarray[$i]); $i++) {
    $pairs[] = array($value => $inputarray[$i]);
  }
}
```

The for loop sets `$i` as the key of the current array element + 1, so it'll never be referencing itself, and will never reference any previous array members.

Comment: Thank you @billyonecan, this worked for me, completely fits my case **thanks for help** its helpful being in this family

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<$inputarray.length;$i++){
    $k=$i+1;
    for($j=$k; $j<$inputarray.length;$j++){    
        $outputarray[] = array($inputarray[$i] => $inputarray[$j]); 

    }
}
```